# Aligning form labels input-group-prepend with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a python/django website with bootstrap, but i'm running into something i can't seem to solve on my own. Been a while since i've worked with python/django/bootstrap, so i might be missing something?

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.non_field_errors }}

    <div class="input-group mb-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend ">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Player Name</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="player_name" name='player_name' placeholder="Player Name">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend ">
            <span class="input-group-text " id="basic-addon1">Recruiter</span>
        </div>
        {{ form.recruiter }}
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Notes</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Accepted</span>
        </div>
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg" aria-label=".form-select-lg" id='accepted' name='accepted'>
            <option value="Not Yet" selected>Not Yet</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Vote is up</span>
        </div>
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm" id='vote_is_up' name='vote_is_up'>
            <option value="No" selected>No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="archived" hidden>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault" hidden>
            Archived
        </label>
    </div>
    {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %} 
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

As you can see on the image below, the 'labels' are all unaligned. I would like them the be all just as long so they line up nicely

[image: Eventual outcome]

Comment: Unaligned = a little more space on top than bottom?

Comment: No, i meant the labels like player name, recruiter, notes, accepted and vote is up to be just as long. I think i fixed it with a style="width: 115px;" in the <spawn> but not sure that's how you should do it with bootstrap?

Comment: The labels only take up as much space as there is content within, that is Bootstrap default. So `Notes` will be shorter than `Player Name` for example. If you need them all to be same, then you need add the `width` in custom css as you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

As i've said in the comments myself and Siddharth Bhansali confirmed, i need to set a fixed width in the custom css of the span. So those lines became:

```
<span class="input-group-text " id="basic-addon1" style="width: 115px;">
```

[image]